# Mulesoft: Remove duplicate records by checking dateField using dataweave

Tags: duplicates, mule, esb, dataweave

I have a csv file with following data:

```
Id,Name,Type,date
1,name1,employee,25/04/2017
2,name2,contrator,26/04/2017
3,name3,employee,25/04/2017
4,name4,contrator,26/04/2017
5,name5,employee,24/04/2017
6,name6,contrator,24/04/2017
7,name7,employee,25/04/2017
8,name8,contrator,24/04/2017
9,name9,employee,24/04/2017
10,name10,contrator,26/04/2017
6,name6,employee,27/04/2017
11,name11,employee,27/04/2017
12,name12,contrator,27/04/2017
```

If It has two rows with same Id number. One of the row should be removed by checking the latest date. The row with older date should be removed.
For example, above input has two rows of data with ID no 6. The row with date 24/04/2017 should be removed. The output should be like this

```
Id,Name,Type,date
1,name1,employee,25/04/2017
2,name2,contrator,26/04/2017
3,name3,employee,25/04/2017
4,name4,contrator,26/04/2017
5,name5,employee,24/04/2017
6,name6,employee,27/04/2017
7,name7,employee,25/04/2017
8,name8,contrator,24/04/2017
9,name9,employee,24/04/2017
10,name10,contrator,26/04/2017
11,name11,employee,27/04/2017
12,name12,contrator,27/04/2017
```

I need to achieve this using Dataweave. Please provide me a solution or suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the dataweave you are looking for:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
%var toDate = (str) -> str as :date { format: "dd/MM/yyyy" }
%var maxDate = (a, b) -> a when toDate(a.date) > toDate(b.date) otherwise b
---
payload groupBy $.Id 
    pluck $ map ($ reduce ((val, acc) -> maxDate(val, acc)))
```

[image]